# "Making a Purchase" in Python tutorial in Codecademy

Tags: python

**The instructions for the assignment are:**

Define a function `compute_bill` that takes one argument `food` as input.
In the function, create a variable `total` with an initial value of zero.
For each item in the food list, add the price of that item to total.
Finally, return the total.
Ignore whether or not the item you're billing for is in stock.

Note that your function should work for any food list.

The following is my attempt to solve the problem

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}
def compute_bill(food):
    total=0
    for item in food:
        for items in prices:
         if food[item]==prices[items]:
            print prices[item]
            total+=prices[item]
         else:
            print 'not found'
    return total
compute_bill(['apple', 'jok'])
```

**The error I'm getting is:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "python", line 26, in 
>     File "python", line 21, in compute_bill
>   KeyError: 'jok'

I put a random list with "jok" in it as it said for any list. Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are facing occurs because you are trying to get the price of the item `jok` from your dictionary which doesn't contain that key.

In order to avoid that error, it is best to check if the key you are checking exists, like so:

```
if item in prices:
            total+= prices[item]
```

So given that, the code should look like this:

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}
def compute_bill(food):
    # Set total variable to 0
    total=0
    # Loop over every item in food list to calculate price
    for item in food:
        # Check that the item in the food list really exists in the prices
        # dicionary
        if item in prices:
            # The item really exists, so we can get it's price and add to total
            total+= prices[item]
    print total
compute_bill(['apple', 'jok', 'test', 'banana'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Food is a list, not a dictionary - So you are not able to look up an item in the list via anything other than an index in the list. But there is no need to re look up the item since you're already iterating over it.

You also can't iterate over a dictionary so that needs altering also

```
for items in prices:
 if food[item]==prices[items]:
```

should just be

```
for key, val in prices.items():
    if item == key:
```

But that still doesn't make sense, instead you just need to find out if the item is in the dictionary

```
for item in food:
    price = prices.get(item)
    if price: 
        total+=price
```